# How to remove untitled env

Tags: python, python-venv, anaconda3

How to remove untitled env

[Terminal]

```
(base) sehyeon@sehyeonui-MacBookAir ~ % conda env list
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/sehyeon/anaconda3
base                  *  /Users/sehyeon/miniforge3
ds_study                 /Users/sehyeon/miniforge3/envs/ds_study
```

How to remove first env?

Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried `conda remove --name ENV_NAME --all` but this env don't have name.
So I can't remove this.